# No WebGL support for Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, webgl, runescape

The 2 solutions/workarounds I found searching askubuntu didn't work so far. Going to *chrome://flags* and enabling **Override software rendering list** didn't work. Also, starting Google Chrome with "LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 google-chrome" doesn't seem to work. Chrome opens and works normally, but WebGL isn't working. I receive the following terminal output:

```
$ LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 google-chrome[6436:6436:0924/110923:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js:319:20", source: https://www.google.com.br/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8 (0)
[6436:6436:0924/110924:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at inject_code (chrome-extension://gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio/js/cs_inject.js:21:13)", source: https://www.google.com.br/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8 (0)
[6436:6457:0924/110924:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(922)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for goldenticket.disconnect.me failed err=-8181
[6436:6464:0924/110927:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Google Chrome 45 64-bit. I have a Nvidia GeForce 730m and driver 340.76 is installed and working 100% (I can play graphically heavy games on Steam). WebGL is working on Firefox 41 (I can see a rotating cube on https://get.webgl.org/), but it's not working on Google Chrome. This is what *chrome://gpu* shows me:

**Graphics Feature Status**

- Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Flash: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Flash Stage3D: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration
  unavailable
- Compositing: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
- Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Video Encode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- WebGL: Unavailable

I guess it's not a driver related issue, since WebGL is working on Firefox. Could someone please help me getting WebGL to work on Google Chrome too? I would like to play Runescape using Chrome.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have hardware acceleration. Is it enabled in Settings>Advanced>Use hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

> For WebGL to work in Google Chrome (and Chromium), Here are the steps to enable WebGL in Google Chrome.

Step 1: Open Google Chrome

Step 2: Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar

Step 3: Press `Ctrl + f` and type ” `Rendering list` “, “Override software rendering list” 
should come up, Now click on Enable and restart the browser.

Step 4: Completely kill Chrome: Type `killall chrome` into a console.

Step 5: Start Chrome

[image]

> Now check      `chrome://gpu/`

[image]

> http://webglreport.com/

[image]

[Source](http://prasopensource.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/how-to-enable-webgl-in-google-chrome-browser-in-gnulinux/)